# Patching installed software on Mac

Tags: macos, updates, patch, dmg

I created an application and I distribute it to end-users in a 500MB big DMG file. When I regularly release bugfixes of the application, I do not want that my users have to download a 500MB big DMG file again and again.

I'm looking for a solution similar to MSP on Windows or delta RPM on Linux, so in the update I want to distribute only the changed files, or even better, the binary patches of changed files. Are there any tools for this job?

Comment: incremental patching is a pretty big subject... and will involve lots of different strategies... usually you will have a new version of the main executable, some of your libraries may change... and resources could be removed or added... you can manage some or all of these by yourself or implement something like rdiff or a version control server to do it without building packages.